# Printing matching subgroups in a perl one liner

Tags: regex, sed, perl

I have the regex[1]

```
(/foo/bar/(GW|GREV)[^/]*).*
```

I was able to get this to work with GNU sed with

```
sed -n 's/\(\/foo\/bar\/\(GW\|GREV\)[^\/]*\).*/\1/p'
```

But that was a modern GNU sed and I'm on Solaris 10 with an ancient sed.  Maybe it is possible to port it but that's beyond my ability.  I do have perl 5.8 available to me, though, so my question: how can I get the matching subgroup printed in a perl one liner?

---

[1]
The gist of it is I want to match all directories that match the form /foo/bar/GWxxx, /foo/bar/GREVxxx and print that root directory.  So for the following strings, I always get `/foo/bar/GREV123` as the captured group:

```
/foo/bar/GREV123
/foo/bar/GREV123/
/foo/bar/GREV123/etc
```

Comment: Have you tried `grep`? http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html Would be easy enough to get a listing then pipe it into `grep`. If `/foo/bar/GREV123` is what you are after then you can limit your expression in grep to only give you that in the return.

Comment: I can try grep, but once again i just have grep/egrep from solaris 10, not the fully-featured GNU grep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
perl -pe 's{^(/foo/bar/(GW|GREV)[^/]*).*?$}{$1}o'
```

Deparsed version:

```
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    s[^(/foo/bar/(GW|GREV)[^/]*).*?$][$1]o;
}
continue {
   die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
```

P.S. You may add code to supress printing duplicated entries